# Android WebView inject JavaScript between onPageStarted and onPageFinished

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I need to inject some JavaScript into my web page that I'm loading into a `WebView`, but injecting it at `onPageFinished` is too late and `onPageStarted` is too soon. Any way I can inject it between this two events?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progress.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:registerObjectDetailsCallback(" +
                                    "function(details) {" +
                                        "if (details.length == 1) {" +
                                            "window.location.href = 'callback:' + escape(details[0]);" +
                                        "} else if (details.length > 1) {" +
                                            "alert('Error: callback set by registerObjectDetailsCallback was passed multiple selection');" +
                                        "}" +
                                    "}" +
                                ");");
        Log.d("onPageFinished: ", "JavaScript registered.");
    }
}
```

Comment: injecting code from android?

Comment: @DIVA Yes, so the code in my post will be run by the android app.

Comment: i m unable to understand parameter for loadUrl ? its not valid

Comment: @DIVA It is, it's just running a bit of javascript. Same as typing into the address bar of a browser `javascript:alert('hello')`

Comment: ok can u send me ur demo project incase it is small i can try at my end

Comment: @DIVA I cannot as I can't give you access to the web page that this code should be run on.

Comment: ok any apk u can provide?

Comment: I can send you an apk of the app, but you won't be able to reproduce this issue, as you won't have access to the web page that responds to that particular piece of code as I said before.

Comment: ohh , ok i think after on start u can used synronized or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't end up using this in the end, I came up with a better solution - but what you can do is use the `onProgressChanged` method in `WebChromeClient` in order to perform actions at certain stages of loading.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        // Do something cool here
    }
});
```

Comment: hi i'm struggling with this problem too, by inject js in somewhere else beside in onPageFinish , you said you have a better solution, Is it something else other than this one you posted (I mean do it on onProgressChanged), sorry for not quiet sure to explain the problem, because I'm not mother tongue in English